# Bamboo/Jmeter scripting and integration

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, integration-testing, bamboo

I need to produce a number of component integration tests to fit into an existing framework composed of Jmeter and run via Bamboo.

My problem is that I know nothing of Bamboo.

Working in a Linux environment.

Does anyone have any recommendations for either basic tutorials for Bamboo, or links to existing questions on here which would form a good start point for me?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea of adding a JMeter test under continuous integration system control is having unattended JMeter test executions basing on triggers (on version control system commit, periodically, on-demand, whatever).

There are several ways of running a JMeter test via Bamboo, the easiest would be either running a shell [Script](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/script-289277046.html) or [Custom Command Executable](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/custom-command-executable-289277045.html).

The results can be viewed and analysed using [JMeter Aggregator](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jmeterAggregator/server/overview) plugin.

See [How to Run JMeter in a Continuous Integration Environment With Bamboo](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-continuous-integration-environment-bamboo) for step-by-step configuration instructions and examples.

Comment: Thanks @dmitri-t, I'll have a look through that site and see if I can get that to work in my environment.